# Question about replacement

Tags: replacement

I get from as a solution from `Solve` the following output:

```
output = {ConditionalExpression[C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}
```

> {ConditionalExpression[C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]}

Why do I get **two different results** if I execute the following two lines after each other?

```
% /. FindInstance[AllTrue[%, # >= 0 &], C[1]]
output /. FindInstance[AllTrue[%, # >= 0 &], C[1]]
```

> {{84}}
>
> {{Undefined}}

Comment: Because in the second you have `AllTrue[%,...]` which applies to the _previuos_ calculation, i.e. the `{{84}}` one. Go with `output /. FindInstance[AllTrue[output, # >= 0 &], C[1]]` to have it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
output = {ConditionalExpression[C[1], C[1] ∈ Integers]};

% /. FindInstance[AllTrue[%, # >= 0 &], C[1]]

(*  {{84}}  *)
```

Since there is an intervening result, in the second case `%` needs to be changed to `%%`. See documentation for [`Out`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html)

```
output /. FindInstance[AllTrue[%%, # >= 0 &], C[1]]

(*  {{84}}  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you execute the second line, you should replace `%` in the `AllTrue` command by `output`. The way it is written right now, the `%` in the second line picks up `{{84}}` instead of `{ConditionalExpression[C[1], C[1] \[Element] Integers]}`.